# How can I show specific data from SQL data base in MVC (AngularJS, HTML, PHP)

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, model-view-controller

I am working on a simple web app that reads name matching a certain ID, as input, and displays names in an HTML table. Later on, I may consider pagination (with show more button, etc).

I'm not getting any errors in my PHP error log or in my console, but nothing is showing up when I open the page.

My database is named DataList, has columns named `Name` and `ID`.

The PHP (running on backend):

```
$sql = "SELECT Name FROM DataList WHERE ID=1";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$htmlTable = '<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
          <tr>';
$haveTable = 'no';


if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  $haveTable = 'yes';
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $htmlTable .= "<tr><td>".$row["Name"]."</td></td>";
  }
  $htmlTable .= "</tr>";
  return "$htmlTable";
} else {
  echo "You haven't input anything yet!";
}

mysqli_close($db);

?>
```

My HTML snippet: (the file is called data.html, in a views folder and within a div in the body)

```
<form id="nameViewForm" >
        <script> window.onload="displayNames()" ; </script>
        <div id="nameTable"></div>
        <button type="button" ng-click="switchForm('#dataInputForm')">Input 
Data</button>
</form>
```

My JS Controller (file called user.js, in a controllers folder.)

```
    app.controller('dataCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

        $http.get("<website>/displayNames.php").then(function(res){

        });

        var config = {
            headers : {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8;'
            }
        }


        $scope.displayNames = function() {
          var data = $.param({

          });
          $http.get("<website>/displayNames.php", data, config).then(function(res) {
              console.log();
              var table = data.property;
              $scope.nameTable = table;
          });
        }

    });
```

Is my logic fundamentally flawed or am I messing up in one of the sections?

Comment: wild guess but try `return "$htmlTable";` into `echo $htmlTable;` does that make the response show in the console?

Comment: There still isn't anything in the console after switching that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how i usually display data in my tables.

First I make a table in the html file like so:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="n in names">
            <td>{{n.name}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and use ng-repeat to display the data.

in my js i get all the names and place them into a scope variable.

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);


app.controller('dataCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {

    $scope.getnames = function(){
        $http.get('<website>/displayNames.php')
        .then(function(response) {
            $scope.names = response.data;

        });
    }

    $scope.getnames();
});
```

And in my php file I simple echo json data like so

```
$sql = "SELECT Name FROM DataList WHERE ID=1";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

$names = array();


if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $names[] = $row;
    }
} 

$JSONReady = json_encode($names);

echo $JSONReady;
```